# Authorization with UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, basic-authentication, urlfetch

I've read many questions and haven't found my issue. I want to access a remote file and save it to my GDrive. Google refuses a URL with user/pswd in the URL. Without auth, the code looks like:

```
fURL = "https://example.com/file.pdf";
finfo = downloadFile(fURL,'PDFs');

function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
[...]
```

Predictably, this produces a 401 Unauthorized error.

So, I add options to the call:

```
fURL = "https://example.com/file.pdf";
finfo = downloadFile(fURL,'PDFs');

function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {
  var options =
      {
        method : "get",
        headers : {
          "Authorization": "Basic base64userpswd"
        },
        muteHttpExceptions : true
      };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, options);
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
[...]
```

With only this change, Google now reports:

Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url (line 26, file "Code")

I've tried it with and without quoting the options keys, same. I cannot see how the fileURL argument is being lost due to the inclusion of options. Apologies if it's something really dumb, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Although I cannot understand about `line 26` of `Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url (line 26, file "Code")` and your actual script, can I ask you about the method for running the script? For example, you run the function of `downloadFile` in your question at the script editor, at first, `finfo = downloadFile(fURL,'PDFs');` is run with the arguments, and also `function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {}` is run without the arguments. Is your issue related to this?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first use of the gscript interface. I had a number of scripts listed at the left, and while working on the last one, I did not realize it was always running script #1 at the top when I clicked RUN. All good now, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was repeatedly making adjustments to my script, and was baffled at getting the same response regardless. But this is my first experience with gscripts. I had a number of scripts listed at the left, and while working on the last one, I did not realize it was always running script #1 at the top when I clicked RUN. Once I isolated my script as the only one in the project, it ran as expected.